# Why do simulated results differ to calculated results?

Tags: multisim, calculus

Why, when using a program such as multisim, do the simulated results within the program differ slightly to those calculated analytically.

Would there be any reasons other than rounding errors in calculations and the fact that multisim uses ideal components?

For example, I have a circuit; a 3 phase unbalanced load connected up in star, with one leg having a resistor and capacitor, one leg having a resistor and inductor, and one leg that has only a resistor. In multisim I have used z blocks for the 2 legs and a resistor for the leg with no xl or xc.

I've calculated the I through each phase, I for the neutral, and the total power dissipated. My simulated results for the currents are around 1-2mA out (which would be accepted as correct), and the power dissipated is about 200W out (again would still be accepted.)

For distinction criteria I am to compare the results and explain why they are different, and apart from the reasons listed above I cannot think of any, however for a distinction I would be expected to write more than just a paragraph.

Comment: Any simulation program is highly likely to take into account far more parameters than a person would doing a manual calculation. Provide an example and someone will be more likely to provide a formal answer.

Comment: Added some context. The answers I'm receiving are undoubtedly correct, but I'm just looking for a couple of reasons as to why they may be slightly out that I can expand on in greater detail.

Comment: How many significant figures differ? How many s.f. did you do the calculation to? How many cycles were required for the simulation to converge? Computer floating point has a finite precision and can accumulate errors over the course of a simulation.

Comment: 3 SF in both cases, and it's always a case of 3 SF differing. Eg, A might = 2.058 when calc and the simulated it will be 1.816. Dumb q but how would i work out the cycles? I have very basic knowledge of the software.

Comment: 'For distinction criteria' sounds like a homework question to me. Simulate and calculate something simpler, then increase the complexity, change the simulator step size and integration method, see where the divergence between them increases, then relate it to what you have changed or added. You want a distinction, do some distinction-quality investigation.

Comment: 100 to 200 mA out ? What are the actual current measurements using sim and using a calculator? Also, how did you use sim to calculate an RMS current (presumably that is what you did) and how much settling time did you give it.

Comment: @Andyaka After checking the simulation to grab the results Ive noticed a meter set to dc instead of ac. Results are no as expected, only 1-2mA out, so my bad there.

Comment: Yeah you are Baaaaad!! So 1 or 2mA represent a percentage error of what?

Comment: Yep, feel a bit dumb haha. Error is now 12% so should be good. Put down to things like rounding when changing from polar to rec form in calculations and ideal components in simulator etc.

Comment: 12% still seems like a big error for a circuit using only ideal passive components. Are you sure you used the right kind of Z load?

Comment: I just used a Z=a+jb or -jb block for inductor/capacitor, mainly because that's how I've been shown to do it in lectures. The difference ends up being 2.508 calc and 2.051 sim, and 1.094 calc and 1.097 sim